# C# Windows Forms: Access Controls(Labels, Buttons) in other Classes

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I need to know, how I can access lables or buttons other than in my "Form1"-Class.

My Problem:
I created for example labels, buttons via the design viewer. Now I can access
them in my Form1 Class. (`testlabel.Enabled == true`) just for example.

What I CAN'T do: Access those labels, buttons in another class! Let's say
I have a class "second-class" and I want to have a method there, that changes
the property of a label to

```
`testlabel.Enabled == false`
```

That's not possible, because in that "second-class" it's not visible.

So, is there an obvious easy solution to make those controls accessible in other classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method in that (Second class) which takes that component (`Label` or `Button` or whatever you want to modify) as parameter into that method.

```
public void disableLabel(Label inputLabel)
{
    inputLabel.Enabled == false
}
```

Create a method like the above.

Now in the form1 class you just to need to call that method and pass your `Label` into that method to `Disable` it.

```
SecondClass objSecondClass = new SecondClass();
objSecondClass.disableLabel(testlabel);
```

Comment: As an extension to this concept, you can also pass the entire form to methods of the second class e.g. `public void MySecondClassAlgorithm(Form1 form) { ... }`.  This method can now access all of the public properties and methods of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Every control in a form class is created by default with its property `Modifiers` set to `Private`
If you change it to `Public` you could access the control instance from another class.

However this is really a bad practice to follow. Messing with the visibility of the control is dangerous and could cause very complicated bugs to resolve.

If you really need to change something in your form class then provide a public method and call this method to change the internal functionality of the target form